# "for someone to do something" as a noun phrase

Tags: phrases, complementation, infinitive-clauses, functions, conjunctions

Can we use the structure: `for + sb/sth + to + verb + ...` As a noun phrase?

For example, in the following sentence:

> The best approach to address this issue is [noun (phrase)]

Can we complete the sentence like this?
Is it grammatically current? If it is, what grammar is used?

> The best approach to address this issue is for the government to introduce green taxes.

Answer (score 5):

Whether this a noun phrase or not, depends on your grammar. However, the more important point is: Can we use "For someone to do something" as the Complement of a verb (or indeed as the Subject of a clause)?

The answer is like this:

We can use *to*-infinitivals without the word *for*:

- To err is human.
- The best thing would be to give the elephant a bun.
- I arranged to leave.

In the sentences above there is no *for* introducing the infinitival clause. However, notice that these clauses have no Subject. Often, if we want to use a Subject with an infinitival clause, we need to start the clause with the word *for*:

- For people to err is human.
- The best thing would be for Bob to give the elephant a bun.
- I arranged for the ship to leave.

The Original Poster's sentence is grammatically correct:

> The best approach to address this issue is for the government to introduce green taxes.

This verb uses an infinitival clause as a Complement of the verb *BE*. It is a grammatically formulated sentence. The reason that *for* is required here is that the infinitival clause has a Subject, *the government*. If we don't use it the sentence is ungrammatical:

- *The best approach to address this issue is the government to introduce green taxes. (wrong).

Comment: One of the best answers I came across recently. Very happy I did. Would it be worth noting that the Subject of the infinitival clause and the Subject of the sentence are different in your examples? I thought it wasn't immediately clear.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach to address this issue is for the government to introduce green taxes.

There is nothing wrong with the structure presented by the OP, but the sentence formed by him isn't according to the structure. It should be:

The best approach for the government to address this issue is to introduce green taxes.

Alternatively, I think, you can say:

The best approach for the govetnment to address this issue is that it introduce green taxes.

Comment: I want the sentence to convey the meaning that the best possible action is ... not the best action that the government can take.

Comment: user2136334,  Well, you can say: The best approach to address this issue is that the government introduce green taxes.